# How to solve "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined" for slick.js

Tags: javascript, shopify, slick.js

I'm trying to make some customization in a Shopify theme (the Brooklyn one). In this theme, there is a file `theme.js.liquid` in which they import the slicker:

```js
/*
     _ _      _       _
 ___| (_) ___| | __  (_)___
/ __| | |/ __| |/ /  | / __|
\__ \ | | (__|   < _ | \__ \
|___/_|_|\___|_|\_(_)/ |___/
                   |__/

 Version: 1.8.1
  Author: Ken Wheeler
 Website: http://kenwheeler.github.io
    Docs: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick
    Repo: http://github.com/kenwheeler/slick
  Issues: http://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues

 */

!function(i){"use strict";"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],i):"undefined"!=typeof exports?module.exports=i(require("jquery")):i(jQuery)}(function(i){"use strict";var e=window.Slick||{};(e=function(){var e=0;return function(t,o){var s,n=this;n.defaults={accessibility:!0,adaptiveHeight:!1,appendArrows:i(t),appendDots:i(t),arrows:!0,asNavFor:null,prevArrow:
```

I cut the end of the line because it's way too long.

Then in the chrome console, if I do:

```js
$('.slick-slider').slick('slickUnfilter');
```

It returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slickUnfilter' of undefined at n.fn.init.i.fn.slick

And I got this error for any slick function (like 'slickFilter', 'slickAdd', 'slickRemove', ...).
I searched for this error and from what I understood it's because those methods are defined but not initialized, or because there are initialized twice. However the slicker is imported within the theme and it should have been done correctly. What can I do then?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** As it was pointed out, there was 2 sliders (one on the home page and one on another page). And when I was coding in the chrome console, I was on the other page. This is why I got the last error, because I guess the slider was already initialized in the main page. The solution was to give them distinct names.

Comment: Do you happen to have two versions of jQuery included?

Comment: I don't think. The theme should have imported it only once.

Comment: You need to check for another issues and conflicts, it works well on the latest version https://prnt.sc/wd58n1

Comment: Indeed when I did it in my hero banner on the home page (like you), there was no error. However when I try to do it from a product page in mobile version (so the slider appears), I have the error. Anyway it's a good to know that there is no error for the slider in the home page.

Comment: okay, let me check it for the product page as well, there nothing mention regarding any specific page so just check it for the homepage.

Comment: Alright, I found the core of the problem. As you noticed, both slider on the home page and on the product page have the same name. That's why I got the error when I'm on my product page, because the slider have already been initialized on the home page. The solution is to give them distinct names. However, I don't know how to do that because on the html code, it never give the class slick-slider, so I don't know where this name come from. Anyway I'll edit the question with the latest news.

Comment: I have checked it for the product page and found these things, it works with `$('.product-single__media-group').slick('slickUnfilter');` over product page, I have checked and this is due to the second slider init for navigation over the same page and `slick-slider` generate error.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wd614i

Comment: Indeed, using the class .product-single__media-group make it work. Thank you for this suggestion!

Comment: And for the slicker name, indeed in the chrome console I can see the class .slick-slider. But in the code of my product-template.liquid, I can't find it.

Comment: @OnkarSingh If you want, you can post your comment about using the other class .product-single__media-group in an answer. I will then accept the answer so everyone can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error over the Shopify Brooklyn theme product page due to `slick-slider` class mix-up, and if you want to you the slick function called `slickUnfilter`.

You need to use a separate class rath then `slick-slider` over the product page because the same class is added by `slick.JS` and it presents all `slick` instances on the page.

So like the Brooklyn theme you need to find another class that is added to the parent slider element.

You can use `$('.product-single__media-group').slick('slickUnfilter');`, it work well.

Thanks

Comment: Amazing! I was stuck for so long on this issue.

Comment: Although, now this breaks the website on desktop view.